# When is a string an object when using "in" operator?

Tags: javascript, string

Why does this:

```
console.log('length' in new String('test'))
```

return **true**, whereas this:

```
console.log('length' in String('test'))
```

throw a TypeError?

> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in test

Comment: Have a look at the meaning of [Explicit Coercion](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20&%20grammar/ch4.md#explicit-coercion) and [Implicit Coercion](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20&%20grammar/ch4.md#implicit-coercion) in JavaScript.

Comment: @MarcoL nice reference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has string *primitives* and string *objects*. (And similarly for numbers and booleans.) In your first test, you're testing an object, because `new String()` creates an object. In your second, you're testing a primitive, because `String(x)` just converts `x` to string. Your second test is exactly the same as writing `console.log('length' in 'test');`

The [`in` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) (you have to scroll down a bit) throws a type error if you use it on something that isn't an object; it's the fifth of six steps under *RelationalExpression : RelationalExpression `in` ShiftExpression*:

5. If Type(*rval*) is not Object, throw a **TypeError** exception.

(This is somewhat to my surprise; most things that require an object coerce primitives to objects, but not `in`.)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer using the specification as reference!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
typeof String('test') -> "string"
typeof new String('test') -> "object"
```

`in` will work only with objects.

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the
>   specified object.
>   You must specify an object on the right side of the in operator. For
>   example, you can specify a string created with the String constructor,
>   but you cannot specify a string literal.

```
var color1 = new String("green");
"length" in color1 // returns true

var color2 = "coral";
// generates an error (color2 is not a String object)
"length" in color2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var s_prim = 'foo'; //this return primitive
var s_obj = new String(s_prim);//this return String Object

console.log(typeof s_prim); // Logs "string"
console.log(typeof s_obj);  // Logs "object"
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the
>   specified object.

```
   "length" in s_obj // returns true       

   "length" in s_prim // generates an error (s_prim is not a String object)
```

In operator is used only for objects,arrays